# Google+ API - Moments visibility

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I am currently researching Google+ REST API to post to a user's stream.
The basic requirements are:

1. The post should be created without user's review using server side request (user should give his permission to post on his behalf in the future).
2. The post must be visible to all user's friends.

As i understand from reading the documentation, posting to the stream without actually getting permission in creation time from the user is impossible, however, creating 'moments' doesn't require permission upon-posting, so the user should give his permission when authorizing the app.

Since i didn't find anything that explains how can a moment be created to be visible to all user's friends - can someone who is familiar with this API explain how visibility of a moment is being determined and on which step? reference to an API documentation would be good as well, but i didn't find any.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The moment methods do not write directly to a user's Google+ stream. They instead write to a user's profile, and are not necessarily viewable by others depending on the user's preferred sharing settings.

[Manage app activities in Google](https://developers.google.com/+/web/app-activities/)

During authorization the user chooses who their activity is visible to.

[image]

Once authorized a user should be able to see their [own activities on Google+](https://plus.google.com/apps/activities) and you can view other people's activities by clicking on an app from their profile about page.

[image]

Comment: So it means that once a moment was created with public visibility, it won't be shown to other users unless they enter my profile and go to the activities section?